# Calculated column won't be created!

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to create a calculated column. I tried below formulas:

```
=([ContractFinalKm]-[Present/RealFinalKm])/ABS([Present/RealFinalKm])
```

AND

```
=([Present/RealFinalKm]*100)/[ContractFinalKm]
```

Neither of the above formulas worked.

I have two SharePoint lists one of them works properly with the formulas but the other one doesn't.

Comment: Is your column name "Present/RealFinalKm" with `/` in it or you are trying to divide `Present` by `RealFinalKm`? Also, if the same formulas are working in another list then I will suggest you to check the column settings in both list and make the exactly similar...Column name (check for extra spaces), data type and required property should be same everywhere.

Comment: / is in the title!! ok!

Comment: What's the error message say? And are each of those columns numeric types? Are any of them lookups?